# Transfer multiple files simultaneously with SFTP on Windows

Tags: ssh, sftp

I am looking for a way to upload multiple files from my local server to my remote server, both running Windows.

Currently I have been copying the files manually. Any third party software like WinSCP's solution is invited, as long as the software will enable me to upload multiple files and runs on Windows. Any solution will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

WinSCP supports [simultaneous uploads](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/transfer_queue):

[image: Background Transfers Queue List]

---

On [transfer options dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_copy), check *"add to transfer queue"*:

[image]

---

You can also [make queued transfer the default option in preferences](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_background).

Comment: Martin, I was just about to post exactly the same. I'll upvote yours. :)